# zero copy in Qt application in C++

Tags: c++, qt, zero-copy

here is the program that I wrote to implement zero copy in a Qt application but getting some errors written below:

```
//client.h
#ifndef CLIENT1_H
#define CLIENT1_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
#include <QtNetwork/QtNetwork>
class Client: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  Client(QObject* parent = 0);
  ~Client();
  void start(QString address, quint16 port);
public slots:
  void startTransfer();
private:
  QTcpSocket client;
};

#endif // CLIENT1_H

//client.cpp
#include "client1.h"
#include <QtNetwork/QHostAddress>
#include <MSWSockDef.h>
#include <MSWSock.h>
Client::Client(QObject* parent): QObject(parent)
{
  connect(&client, SIGNAL(connected()),
          this, SLOT(startTransfer()));
}

Client::~Client()
{
  client.close();
}

void Client::start(QString address, quint16 port)
{
  QHostAddress addr(address);
  client.connectToHost(addr, port);
}

void Client::startTransfer()
{
    int TransmitFile( client,
                      hfile,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      TF_USE_SYSTEM_THREAD
                    );
}

//main.cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "client1.h"
#include <QtNetwork/QtNetwork>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    HFILE hfile;
    //Creates an instance of ofstream, and opens example.txt
    ofstream a_file ( "example.txt" );
    // Outputs to example.txt through a_file
    a_file<<"This text will now be inside of example.txt";
    // Close the file stream explicitly
    hfile = a_file;
    //a_file.close();
    //hfile = a_file.open("example.txt");
    //hfile = a_file.open("example.txt",ios_base::app);
    Client client;
    client.start("127.0.0.1", 8888);

    return a.exec();
}
```

The errors are as below:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\MSWSock.
error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPWSAMSG'

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\MSWSock.h
error: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\MSWSock.h
error: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I know there are errors in transmitfile() api but those can be removed,what about the above errors?`enter code here?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Riateche :MVC++ compiler 10.0 with Qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after doing all above just do run qmake once,it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to include Winsock2.h, can you try that?

Comment: yup it worked,but got some new errors as below:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\WinSock2.h             error: C2011: 'netent' : 'struct' type redefinition

Comment: Remove every other header you have included, #include <MSWSockDef.h>
#include <MSWSock.h>
, include only Wincock2.h

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `Mswsockdef.h` include.

> ...Mswsockdef.h header file which is automatically included in the
>   Mswsock.h header file. The Mswsockdef.h header file should never be
>   used directly.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/hh437207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: thanx.it worked but again now showing errors regarding redefinition in ws2def.h and winsock2.h